# Python: Backoff decoration not catching Error

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to use tweepy to work with Twitter's api. I intended to use [backoff](https://pypi.org/project/backoff/) to easily implement exponential backoff to handle rate limit errors. However, it seems like backoff does not catch rate limit errors when they occur. Here's my code:

```
    @backoff.on_exception(
        backoff.expo,
        tweepy.error.RateLimitError,
    )
    def page_followers(self, user, page_limit=-1):
      for page in tweepy.Cursor(self._api.followers, id=user.id).pages(page_limit):
           yield page
```

My understanding is that backoff should retry if a RateLimitError is thrown after applying `backoff.expo`.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

**edited to fix title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely catching the errors, but it is hitting the maximum number of retries, after which point you will see the RateLimitError exception.  It may work better to use tweepy's built in wait mechanism:

```
self._api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
```